# C++ call virtual method in child class

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

i have the following classes:

```
class A {
protected:
     A *inner;
public:
    ....
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    ....
}

class B: public A {
   ...
   void doSomething() {
       if(inner != NULL)
           inner->doSomething();
   }
   ...
}
```

When I use `inner->doSomething()` I get a segmentation fault.
What should I do in order to call `inner->doSomething()` in the B class?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get a segfault when using inner, it's probably because it does not point to a valid object. How do you initialize inner in B?

Comment: Every A contains an A*? Really? Why?

Comment: Ok, they're looking at each other. I just wanted to check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without an explicit initialization of the member inner, it's possible for it to be both not NULL and point to invalid memory.  Can you show us the code that explicitly initalizes inner?

An appropriate constructor for A would be the following

```
protected:
A() : inner(NULL) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Alternative to JaredPar's suggestion, in the constructor, specify that inner = NULL. Insert breakpoint in the subclass's doSomething() and observe the value of inner?

Comment: was not initializing it, since i expected is would be NULL and the if statement false. i did not know that it would be possible for an object to be both not NULL and point to invalid memory. i just did inner = NULL at B's construtor and solved the problem.

thank you very much.

Comment: BEWARE: for all standard types (pointers, int, float, etc... also called built-in types) the variable is not initialized when built (there is no 'Default Constructors'). Since 'inner' is an attribute of A, it is the responsability of A's constructor to initialize it, otherwise you will have the problem with every child class...

Comment: Ok Matthieu, gonna put the inner initialization at A's constructor, thanks!

Comment: Can be shortened to `A() : inner() { ... }` albeit the more explicit form is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

though if you assign the A* to be the same as the B initialised this pointer you'll get a stack overflow ... Any reason you need the inner?  Can't you just call A::DoSomething()?